# D3JS V6: Multi Line Group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I'm stuck trying to make a multi line graph with D3JS V6. The problem is about group the data (long format) and trying to plot the path for every group.

My data follows this structure:

| Sexo | Año | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 2000 | 25 |
| Male | 2001 | 58 |
| Female | 2000 | 55 |
| Female | 2001 | 75 |
| Total | 2000 | 80 |
| Total | 2001 | 133 |

```
    function dataviz2() {

    var dataset;
    h = 400
    w = 650
    padding = 40
    count = 0

    // Convertir Strings a Fechas
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y')

    // Convertir Fechas a Strings
    var parseDate = d3.timeFormat('%Y')

    var rowConverter = function (d) {
        return {
            Sexo: d.Sexo,
            Año: parseTime(d.Año),
            N: parseInt(d.N),
        }
    }

    d3.csv('data.csv', rowConverter).then(function (data) {
        dataset = data
        dataset.sort(function (x, y) {
            return d3.ascending(x.Año, y.Año)
        })
        dataBySex = d3.group(data, d => d.Sexo)
        dataBySexGr = Array.from(dataBySex, ([sexo, value]) => ({ sexo, value }))
        console.log(dataBySex)
        console.log(dataBySexGr)



        chart()
    })

    function chart() {

        // Scale X
        xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([
                d3.min(dataset, function (d) { return d.Año }),
                d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.Año })
            ])
            .range([padding, w - padding])

        // Scale Y
        yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.N })])
            .range([h - padding, padding])

        // Create Axis
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

        var svg = d3.select('#dataviz1')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)

        let id = 0;
        const ids = function () {
            return "line-" + id++
        }

        var lines = svg.selectAll('.line')
            .data(dataBySexGr)
            .join('path')
            .attr("class", ids)
            **.attr('d', d => {
                return d3.line()
                    .x(d => x(d.Año))
                    .y(d => y(d.N))
            })**
            .attr('stroke', 'blue')
            .attr('stroke-width', 3)
            .attr('fill', 'none')

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
            .attr('visibility', 'visible')
            .call(xAxis)

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ',0)')
            .attr('visibility', 'visible')
            .call(yAxis)
    }
}
```

What I know after a lot of tries is that the .attr('d', d => ...) is the problem. The argument of that function says "'d' is declared, but its value is never read". When I check the HTML, I receive the different 3 paths I'm looking for but there are no values, are a function.

[image]

I'm really stuck in here, so I appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

d3.line returns a line generator function, you can see that function as the `d` attribute. You need to pass the datum and execute that function to get the path data:

```
.attr('d', d => {
            return d3.line()
                .x(d => x(d.Año))
                .y(d => y(d.N))(d)
        })
```

Or alternatively, you can define the line generator before hand and simply use `.attr('d',line)`:

```
const line = d3.line()
   .x(d => x(d.Año))
   .y(d => y(d.N))

selection.attr("d",line);
```